Feynman-Kac theorem of the weak solution of parabolic PDEs
Is there any reference on the Feynman-Kac theorem of the weak solution of parabolic PDEs? So far I can only find the one for classical solution.

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for but I found this article that mentions the weak solution and has many sources embedded, very much a reputable source:
link
